# Class based Components or functional component?

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, stateful

**Can we build whole react app using functional component or class based components are compulsory for building stateful components?**

Comment: With react-hooks you can simply use functional components to write stateful component

Answer (score 0):

You can use functional components to build the whole app too!
With the help of React Hooks, state management has been made possible with functional components too and for any new projects, its a recommended way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Since React 16.8, they've introduced [react hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html). So now you can build your whole application with functional components using props based approach and with hooks you can have everything that a class based component provides.

So it's your decision with which you need to go. But if you consider testing with 100% factor then functional components with hooks are the best option to opt.

Comment: So we can completely ignore the class based components. right?

Comment: Exactly that's true.